# How do I name a dynamic range generated using lastrow and lastcolumn VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I have a problem, what I am looking for is to make a code that is adaptive (the only thing that is modified is the number of rows, not columns), I need to give it a name because I will use the list as a list range in the advanced filter option and a column integer as criteria range, this is my code, if you suggest something else I accept suggestions.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim LastColumn As Long

Dim StartCell As Range



Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set StartCell = Range("A1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column.End(xlUp).Row)

LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count.End(xlToLeft).Column)

sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn).Select)
```

P.s: I'm a newbie to VBA

Comment: Are the values in a continous range, i.e. no empty columns or rows?
Then you can use Currentregion - which makes everything much easier: 
`sht.range("A1").currentregion` will give you what you need - regardless of the number of rows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion)

Answer (score 0):

No need to have `StartCell` unless you are going to vary it, otherwise you are just using `sht.Cells(1,1)`.  Also, you ended by selecting a range.  Best to avoid `Activate` and `Select`.  If you define the range, you can copy, search, etc.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = sht.Range(1, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

Rng.AutoFilter, Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
```

Comment: Hi Darrell, thank u so much for your help, i'm not familiar with that way to do advanced filter with range, can you give me an example based on what i commented above? To understand you better

Comment: I added a line that shows how to filter on the range.  For more advanced filters, you can view the Microsoft docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.AdvancedFilter, but most cases use the `AutoFilter`